# Show vertical and horizontal cursor till intersection point of line series

Tags: teechart

I want to show vertical and horizontal cursor till intersection point of line series. Please note that the vertical and horizontal cursor lines need not cover the entire axes.

I want show something like below mockup

[Attachment: Mockup Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlk9P.jpg)

I have tried using both cursor. but Unfortunately, I couldn't break both cursor lines after intersection point.
Please let me know if anyone has solution for it.

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: What environment?

Answer (score 0):

You could draw a vertical line and an horizontal line manually at `(On)AfterDraw` event.
Note you can use the `CalcPosValue` function in the Bottom/Left axis to convert axis values to pixels.